# How to automate a C# application using powershell console?

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

## Context

I have a C# application with a GUI for standard users, but for advanced users I want to provide a command line that will allow to manipulate all objects in the app. My idea is to use powershell for that.
If I can run the powershell engine inside my app and I can give this engine a variable that is the root object of my app, then if I can get a powershell console to connect to the hosted engine in my app, then I could do whatever I want. That would allow me to provide powerfull command line for my advanced users.

## Trials

I have read that powershell engine is hostable so my understanding is that I can run the engine "in process" so It could access my objects without marshalling.
I came up with this code to start the powershell engine.

```
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public double A = 10;
        public string B = "toto";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ist = InitialSessionState.Create();
            ist.Variables.Add(new SessionStateVariableEntry("root", new Program(), "root object"));
            var r = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(ist);
            r.Open();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

That effectively starts the powershell engine, and then I can connect using the powershell console.

```
PS C:\Users\Lionel> Enter-PSHostProcess consoleapp1
[Processus :23788]: PS C:\Users\Lionel\Documents> dir variable:
```

I get a console connected to my app but I don't see my root variable.
If I enumerate the runspaces in the host process like that:

```
[Processus :23788]: PS C:\Users\Lionel\Documents> get-runspace

 Id Name            ComputerName    Type          State         Availability
 -- ----            ------------    ----          -----         ------------
  1 Runspace1       localhost       Local         Opened        Available
  2 RemoteHost      localhost       Local         Opened        Busy
```

I see 2 runspaces, the first one is the one I started and the second one is the one that has been created when I connected the powershell console.
If I look into the first runspace like that:

```
[Processus :23788]: PS C:\Users\Lionel\Documents> (get-runspace -id 1).SessionStateProxy.GetVariable("root")

 A B
 - -
10 toto
```

I clearly see my root variable.

## Questions

So my problem is, how do I connect my powershell console to the first runspace and not to create a new one ?
Or, alternatively, how do I force the variables I want into the runspace that are created by remote sessions ?